# DocumentDB Migration Tool - resource name presented contains invalid character '/'

Tags: azure, migration, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use the DocumentDB Migration Tool in order to sequentially insert entries into a CosmosDB database from a CSV file. Entries look like this:

```
Id, Description, BoxId, BoxDescription, BoxWidth, BoxHigh, BoxDepth, Unit
125072,...,1151029,...,860,635,500,...
```

I go through the procedure in the Docs, Successfully verify the connection string and then:

The shown produced command looks like this:

```
/ErrorDetails:All /s:CsvFile /s.Files:C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\Dataprod.csv /t:DocumentDB /t.ConnectionString:AccountEndpoint=https://xxxx.documents.azure.com:443;AccountKey=...;Database=https://xxxx.table.cosmosdb.azure.com:443/; /t.ConnectionMode:Gateway /t.IdField:Id /t.UpdateExisting /t.Collection:ProductCollection /t.PartitionKey:product_key
```

Whenever I run the import step, I get the following error:

```
The resource name presented contains invalid character '/'.
```

I don't understand and can't find which resource is causing this issue.

Comment: Hmmm... something seems a bit off. The `Database=` part shows you using the Table API. `Database` should be the specific Cosmos DB database (which holds your containers/collections).

Comment: @DavidMakogon It's the Connection String that the web app provides, but with the TableName changed to Database. How does a Cosmos Database URI look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Database=https://xxxx.table.cosmosdb.azure.com:443/;` bit is wrong.

The `Database` value should be the name of the `Database` you are migrating into not the `DatabaseAccount` url. You need to change it to the alphanumeric name of your database.